# open ng-template in ngOnInit function not working

Tags: popup, angular6, ngoninit, angularjs-ng-template

I created one ng-template with two text fields. I am trying to open this template popup when my screen loads. But when I pass my id its not working.

```
<ng-template #contentreset let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <p class="modal-title" style="color:black;font-weight: bold;font-size:14px;">Reset password</p>
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                 <
                </div>
```

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.modalService.open(contentreset,{ centered: true }); //here modalservice is NgbModal

});
```

I tried passing the value from other button click but it doesnt worked. How to pass the ng template id while the page loads

Answer (score 0):

your view is not loaded try it on

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

} life cycle of component
```

like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.modalService.open(contentreset,{ centered: true }); //here modalservice is NgbModal

});
```

More on [LIFE_CYCLE_HOOKS](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: i tried it.. not working even on it. using '#contentreset' not worked

Comment: then you may be using it wrong ...have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244566/ngbmodal-open-not-working-in-angular-4

Answer (score 0):

before using  `ngTemplate` we need to create it's tempateRef in component, so try like this

```
 @ViewChild('contentreset ') contentreset : TemplateRef<any>;
```

call this template in `ngAfterViewInit()` for more info have look [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.modalService.open(this.contentreset,{ centered: true }); //here modalservice is NgbModal
 });
```